# ZF3 Introducing Blog Module are you certain you provided it during configuration

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

so im trying to learn the zend framework 3 and I'm stucking now on this error since hours:

```
Unable to resolve service "Blog\Controller\ListController" to a factory; are 
you certain you provided it during configuration?
```

The tutorial I'm learning from:
https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/in-depth-guide/models-and-servicemanager/

The tutorial says at the point "Writing a Factory Class" that this error message is expected but at "Registering Services" it should get fixed, well, it doesn't.

My module.config.php:

```
<?php 
namespace Blog;

use Zend\Config\Factory;
use Zend\Router\Http\Literal;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;


return [

'service_manager' => [
    'aliases' => [
        Model\PostRepositoryInterface::class => Model\PostRepository::class,
    ],
    'factories' => [
        Model\PostRepository::class => InvokableFactory::class,
    ],
],
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        // Update the following line:
        Controller\ListController::class => 
        Factory\ListControllerFactory::class,
    ],
],
'router' => [
    'routes' => [
        'blog' => [
            'type' => Literal::class,
            'options' => [
                'route' => '/blog',
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => Controller\ListController::class,
                    'action' => 'index',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
'view_manager' => [
    'template_path_stack' => [
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ],
],

];
```

my ListController.php:

```
namespace Blog\Controller;

use Blog\Model\PostRepositoryInterface;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class ListController extends AbstractActionController
{
   /**
   * @var PostRepositoryInterface
   */
   private $postRepository;

   public function __construct(PostRepositoryInterface $postRepository)
   {
      $this->postRepository = $postRepository;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code in `module.config.php`, class `Factory\ListControllerFactory` should be exist.

```
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        // Update the following line:
        Controller\ListController::class => Factory\ListControllerFactory::class,
    ],
],
```

And from error messages, it mean the `Blog\Controller\ListController` controller not created. I guess because don't have the factory class.

You can create the `Blog\Controller\ListControllerFactory` class like this,

```
<?php
namespace Blog\Controller;

use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;

class ListControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        return new ListController($container->get(Blog\Model\PostRepository::class));
    }
}
```

Please try, I think that will help

Comment: Hi Dolly, firstly thanks for your answer and sorry for mine late one. I actually already created a ListControllerFactory but with a different return:





   `public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        return new ListController($container->get(PostRepositoryInterface::class));
    }`

Comment: No problem, I think the return was same. Because you access using the `alias` name. So, did you still get the problem?

Comment: Yeah, still the same problem.

Comment: @Kden, hmm if you have create the `Factory` and still get the same error 


   `Unable to resolve service "Blog\Controller\ListController" to a factory; are 
you certain you provided it during configuration?`


I just think you need to update the cache configuration. Just remove it, because it will be recreated when the file not exist


   `rm data/cache/module-config-cache.application.config.cache.php`

Comment: Were you able to resolve this @Kden? If yes what is the resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the line:

```
use Zend\Config\Factory;
```

*Factory* namespace is in conflict with this class.

Answer (score 0):

Check in you **\config\autoload\mezzio-tooling-factories.global.php** file your Factory class entry may be missing.
This was the issue at my end.